# How to install PECL/Memcached?

Tags: memcached, pecl

I have downloaded PECL/Memcached from http://pecl.php.net/package/memcached. Please can anybody explain me how make it works with PHP? Because I  can't find information about that.  I know that is method -  sudo apt-get install php5-memcached, but I get version without SASL support.

P.S. My OS is - Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on [Step by Step - Install PHP PECL Memcache](http://install_php_memcache.onlinephpfunctions.com/) and [How To Install and Use Memcache on Ubuntu 12.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-and-use-memcache-on-ubuntu-12-04).